# Physics Disk Cache in Different Blend File

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation, cache

I have saved cloth and particle simulations to disk, and I would like to save the project with a different name in order to make changes to the scene but retaining these extensive particle and cloth simulations. However, if I save the project as a different version or different name, the project loses its link to the cached files on the disk.

The cache files are saved in the same folder hierarchy as the blend file, and "relative paths" is selected. Library paths was turned on and lite compression turned on. The cache was saved to disk and created a folder with the same name as my blend file.

If I "save as" and rename the file - for example, the original may have been called "Myfile v1" and I now want to make "Myfile v2", the physics disk cache is no longer recognised.

Normally, when saving the cache with the blend file, the cache is saved WITH the file and this is not a problem. The cache for these simulations is very large (about 6 Gb), which is why I saved them to disk, and I want several blend files to use the same simulation.

What is the proper procedure here? Why are the references to the baked physics being lost? How do I relink them?

Comment: Just bumping this....does anyone know how to make sure disk caches are linked when saving a file with a different name?